# Getting UNDEFINED values from Firestore onSnapshot + Promises for my React State

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make a Tweets Application with React and Firebase and I have been suffering when trying to get info from more than 1 collection.

So this is the story:

1. I get the tweets using onSnapshot. All fine here
2. I need more info from 2 other collections: user_preferences and user_photo, so I use .get() within the onSnapshot
3. For managing asynchronism, I resolve my 2 promises before returning the tweet data + details data object for my map function.
4. I made a console.log of my mappedTweet and the values are OKEY. Here I can see the tweet data + details data
5. But my STATE "tweets" just have an array of undefined objects =(. It shows the right number of rows accoroding to my Tweets collection but rows of undefined data, and not the rows of my mappedTweets objects. Why?

Can anyone shed some light?

```
useEffect(() => {
    //------------getting the TWEETS with onSnapshot()-------------
    const cancelSuscription = firestore
      .collection('tweets')
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        const promises = [];
        const tweetsMapped = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
          let tweetAndAuthor;

          const tweetMappped = {
            text: doc.data().text,
            likes: doc.data().likes,
            email: doc.data().email,
            created: doc.data().created,
            uid: doc.data().uid,
            id: doc.id,
          };

          let authorPreference, authorPhoto;

          const userPreferencePromise = firestore
            .collection('user_preferences')
            .where('uid', '==', tweetMappped.uid)
            .get();

          const userPhotoPromise = firestore
            .collection('user_photos')
            .where('id', '==', tweetMappped.uid)
            .get();

          promises.push(userPreferencePromise);
          promises.push(userPhotoPromise);

          //------------getting the AUTHOR USER PREFERENCES with .get()-------------
          userPreferencePromise.then((snapshot2) => {
            authorPreference = snapshot2.docs.map((doc) => {
              return {
                username: doc.data().username,
                color: doc.data().color,
              };
            });
          });

          //------------getting the AUTHOR PHOTO with .get()-------------
          userPhotoPromise.then((snapshot3) => {
            authorPhoto = snapshot3.docs.map((doc) => {
              return {
                photoURL: doc.data().photoURL,
              };
            });
          });

          Promise.all(promises).then((x) => {
            return {
              ...tweetMappped,
              author: authorPreference[0].username,
              authorColor: authorPreference[0].color,
              authorPhoto: authorPhoto[0].photoURL,
            };
          });
        });
        Promise.all(promises).then((x) => {
          setTweets(tweetsMapped);
        });
      });

    return () => cancelSuscription();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you've pushed the promises to your promise array in the state they were **before** you you processed their data. You want to make use of the `Promise.all(docs.map((doc) => Promise<Result>))` pattern here where each document should return a single Promise containing its final result. This then means that the `Promise.all` will resolve with `Result[]`.

**Note:** If inside a Promise you are mutating a variable outside of the Promise (e.g. pushing to an array), that is generally a sign that you are doing something wrong and you should rearrange your code.

Here's a quick example of throwing this together:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let unsubscribed = false;
    
    //------------getting the TWEETS with onSnapshot()-------------
    const cancelSuscription = firestore
      .collection('tweets')
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        const tweetsMappedPromises = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
          let tweetAndAuthor;

          const tweetMappped = {
            text: doc.data().text,
            likes: doc.data().likes,
            email: doc.data().email,
            created: doc.data().created,
            uid: doc.data().uid,
            id: doc.id,
          };

          //------------getting the AUTHOR USER PREFERENCES with .get()-------------
          const userPreferencePromise = firestore
            .collection('user_preferences')
            .where('uid', '==', tweetMappped.uid)
            .limitToFirst(1)
            .get()
            .then((prefDocQuerySnapshot) => {
              const firstPrefDoc = photoDocQuerySnapshot.docs[0];
              const { username, color } = firstPrefDoc.data();
              return { username, color };
            });

          //------------getting the AUTHOR PHOTO with .get()-------------
          const userPhotoPromise = firestore
            .collection('user_photos')
            .where('id', '==', tweetMappped.uid)
            .limitToFirst(1)
            .get()
            .then((photoDocQuerySnapshot) => {
              const firstPhotoDoc = photoDocQuerySnapshot.docs[0];
              return firstPhotoDoc.get("photoURL");
            });

          //--------------------assemble this result---------------------
          return Promises.all([userPreferencePromise, userPhotoPromise])
            .then(([authorPreference, authorPhoto]) => {
              return {
                ...tweetMappped,
                author: authorPreference.username,
                authorColor: authorPreference.color,
                authorPhoto: authorPhoto.photoURL,
              };
            });
        });
        
        Promise.all(tweetsMappedPromises)
          .then((tweetsMapped) => {
            if (unsubscribed) return; // ignore result, dealing with out of date data
            setTweets(tweetsMapped);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            if (unsubscribed) return; // ignore result, dealing with out of date data
            // important! handle errors
          });
      });

    return () => {
      unsubscribed = true;
      cancelSuscription();
    }
  }, []);
```

**Notes:**

- You may benefit from using `async`/`await` syntax here instead.
- On new `onSnapshot` calls, `snapshot.docChanges()` can be used to make it more efficient and speed up rerenders by only updating the entries that have changed (e.g. added/removed/modified). You would use `setTweets(previousTweetsMapped => /* newTweetsMapped */)` for this.

Comment: I've read every single line and I undestood you perfectly Sam. I'm very grateful because of your guidance here and I'm gonna apply and put in practice your advices in order to handle better my code for asynchronous calls. Happy coder here. Thank you so much @samthecodingman

Answer (score 1):

Well, I made it work by changing the model I was using to retrieve the data from Firebase.

I was using an outer onSnapshot with nested promises (I think I was very near here), but now I'm using nested onSnapshots and now app is behaving as expected.

So this is the new useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    let cancelUserPrefSuscription, cancelUserPhotoSuscription;
    
    // First onSnapshot
    const cancelTweetSuscription = firestore
      .collection('tweets')
      .onSnapshot((tweetSnapshot) => {
        const list = [];
        tweetSnapshot.docs.forEach((tweetDoc) => {

          //Second onSnapshot
          cancelUserPrefSuscription = firestore
            .collection('user_preferences')
            .where('uid', '==', tweetDoc.data().uid)
            .onSnapshot((userPrefSnapshot) => {
              userPrefSnapshot.docs.forEach((userPrefDoc) => {

                //Third onSnapshot
                cancelUserPhotoSuscription = firestore
                  .collection('user_photos')
                  .where('id', '==', tweetDoc.data().uid)
                  .onSnapshot((userPhotoSnapshot) => {
                    userPhotoSnapshot.docs.forEach((userPhotoDoc) => {

                      //Taking the whole data i need from all snapshots
                      const newData = {
                        id: tweetDoc.id,
                        ...tweetDoc.data(),
                        author: userPrefDoc.data().username,
                        authorColor: userPrefDoc.data().color,
                        authorPhoto: userPhotoDoc.data().photoURL,
                      };
                      list.push(newData);

                      //Updating my state
                      if (tweetSnapshot.docs.length === list.length) {
                        setTweets(list);
                      }
                    });
                  });
              });
            });
        });
      });

    return () => {
      cancelTweetSuscription();
      cancelUserPrefSuscription();
      cancelUserPhotoSuscription();
    };
  }, []);
```

---

### Edit: Fix from comments of above code

Author: [@samthecodingman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3068190)

For each call to `onSnapshot`, you should keep track of its unsubscribe function and keep an array filled with the unsubscribe functions of any nested listeners. When an update is received, unsubscribe each nested listener, clear the array of nested unsubscribe functions and then insert each new nested listener into the array. For each `onSnapshot` listener attached, a single unsubscribe function should be created that cleans up the listener itself along with any nested listeners.

**Note:** Instead of using this approach, create a `Tweet` component that pulls the author's name and photo inside it.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // helper function
  const callIt = (unsub) => unsub();

  // First onSnapshot
  const tweetsNestedCancelListenerCallbacks = [];
  const tweetsCancelListenerCallback = firestore
    .collection('tweets')
    .onSnapshot((tweetSnapshot) => {
    
      const newTweets = [];
      const expectedTweetCount = tweetSnapshot.docs.length;
    
      // cancel nested subscriptions
      tweetsNestedCancelListenerCallbacks.forEach(callIt);
      // clear the array, but don't lose the reference
      tweetsNestedCancelListenerCallbacks.length = 0;
      
      tweetsNestedCancelListenerCallbacks.push(
        ...tweetSnapshot.docs
          .map((tweetDoc) => { // (tweetDoc) => Unsubscribe
            const tweetId = tweetDoc.id;
          
            //Second onSnapshot
            const userPrefNestedCancelListenerCallbacks = [];
            const userPrefCancelListenerCallback = firestore
              .collection('user_preferences')
              .where('uid', '==', tweetDoc.data().uid)
              .limitToFirst(1)
              .onSnapshot((userPrefSnapshot) => {
                const userPrefDoc = userPrefSnapshot.docs[0];
      
                // cancel nested subscriptions
                userPrefNestedCancelListenerCallbacks.forEach(callIt);
                // clear the array, but don't lose the reference
                userPrefNestedCancelListenerCallbacks.length = 0;
                
                //Third onSnapshot
                const userPhotoCancelListenerCallback = firestore
                  .collection('user_photos')
                  .where('id', '==', tweetDoc.data().uid)
                  .limitToFirst(1)
                  .onSnapshot((userPhotoSnapshot) => {
                    const userPhotoDoc = userPhotoSnapshot.docs[0];
                    
                    // Taking the whole data I need from all snapshots
                    const newData = {
                      id: tweetId,
                      ...tweetDoc.data(),
                      author: userPrefDoc.data().username,
                      authorColor: userPrefDoc.data().color,
                      authorPhoto: userPhotoDoc.data().photoURL,
                    };
                      
                    const existingTweetObject = tweets.find(t => t.id === tweetId);
                    if (existingTweetObject) {
                      // merge in changes to existing tweet
                      Object.assign(existingTweetObject, newData);
                      if (expectedTweetCount === newTweets.length) {
                        setTweets([...newTweets]); // force rerender with new info
                      }
                    } else {
                      // fresh tweet
                      tweets.push(newData);
                      if (expectedTweetCount === newTweets.length) {
                        setTweets(newTweets); // trigger initial render
                      }
                    }
                  });
                userPrefNestedCancelListenerCallbacks.push(userPhotoCancelListenerCallback);
              });
            
            // return an Unsubscribe callback for this listener and its nested listeners.
            return () => {
              userPrefCancelListenerCallback();
              userPrefNestedCancelListenerCallbacks.forEach(callIt);
            }
          })
      );
    });

  // return an Unsubscribe callback for this listener and its nested listeners.
  return () => {
    tweetsCancelListenerCallback();
    tweetsNestedCancelListenerCallbacks.forEach(callIt);
  };
}, []);
```

---

### Edit: Splitting the code in two components

**Note:** Changed limitToFirst(1) --> limit(1). Splitting the fetch logic in two components simplified the onSnapshot approach!

**1.The Parent Component**

```
useEffect(() => {
    const tweetsUnsubscribeCallback = firestore
      .collection('tweets')
      .onSnapshot((tweetSnapshot) => {
        const mappedtweets = tweetSnapshot.docs.map((tweetDoc) => {
          return {
            id: tweetDoc.id,
            ...tweetDoc.data(),
          };
        });
        setTweets(mappedtweets);
      });

    return () => tweetsUnsubscribeCallback();
  }, []);
```

**2.The Child Component: Tweet**

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Helper Function
    const unSubscribe = (unsub) => unsub();

    //------------getting the AUTHOR USER PREFERENCE
    const userPrefNestedUnsubscribeCallbacks = [];
    const userPrefUnsubscribeCallback = firestore
      .collection('user_preferences')
      .where('uid', '==', tweet.uid)
      .limit(1)
      .onSnapshot((userPrefSnapshot) => {
        userPrefNestedUnsubscribeCallbacks.forEach(unSubscribe); // cancel nested subscriptions
        userPrefNestedUnsubscribeCallbacks.length = 0; // clear the array, but don't lose the reference
        //------------getting the AUTHOR PHOTO
        const userPhotoUnsubscribeCallback = firestore
          .collection('user_photos')
          .where('id', '==', tweet.uid)
          .limit(1)
          .onSnapshot((userPhotoSnapshot) => {
            // Taking the whole data I need from all snapshots

            setAuthor({
              author: userPrefSnapshot.docs[0].data().username,
              authorColor: userPrefSnapshot.docs[0].data().color,
              authorPhoto: userPhotoSnapshot.docs[0].data().photoURL,
            });
          });
        userPrefNestedUnsubscribeCallbacks.push(userPhotoUnsubscribeCallback);
      });

    return () => {
      userPrefUnsubscribeCallback();
      userPrefNestedUnsubscribeCallbacks.forEach(unSubscribe);
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: `cancelUserPrefSuscription` and `cancelUserPhotoSuscription` here would only refer to a single tweet's listeners (the last processed), not all of them in the tweets array.

Comment: You're totally right!. So in this approach (with the nested onSnapshots), how would you handle the cleanup function for the listeners?

Comment: Instead of using nested `onSnapshot` calls, create a `Tweet` component that handles rendering it and also fetching the author's name and photo. This will greatly simplify the above code. But to work with nested listeners, you should keep track of the unsubscribe function for each call to `onSnapshot` along with an array filled with the unsubscribe functions of any nested listeners. These should then be grouped together into a single unsubscribe function that cancel the listener along with any nested ones. Remember to reset any nested listeners when the parent is updated too.

Comment: Great suggestion Sam!. The fetch logic in tweet component simplified the callbacks tracking indeed